# Special characters and double quotes issue in PHP

Tags: php, pdo, special-characters, double-quotes, html-entities

I have this kind of value in my db column,

**Judge-Fürstová Mila "Ut enim ad minim veniam"**

I use `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"` to handle all my special characters,

```
class database_pdo
{
    # database handler
    protected $connection = null;

    # make a connection
    public function __construct($dsn,$username,$password)
    {
        try 
        {

            $this->connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
            $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

        }
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            # call the get_error function
            $this->get_error($e);
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...

 }
```

And when I try to print that value in my input field,

```
<input name="title" type="text" value="<?php echo $page->title;?>"/>
```

I only get **Judge-Fürstová Mila** in my input field.

If I use `htmlentities` to fix the double quotes issue,

```
<input name="title" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($page->title);?>"/>
```

I get this in my input field,

**Judge-FÃ¼rstovÃ¡ Mila "Ut enim ad minim veniam"**

So, how can I fix this special characters and double quotes issue at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using htmlspecialchars() instead of htmlentities().

Comment: Thanks. I have just tried but I only get `Judge-Fürstová Mila` instead of `Judge-Fürstová Mila "Ut enim ad minim veniam"`...

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` is actually better than using `htmlentities()` in this case

Comment: @lauthiamkok `htmlspecialchars` should do it, what does the source look like when you use it?

Comment: @lauthiamkok Weird, I tried a simple echo in an input [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/), and it works. Maybe someone else will know if there are some ini settings or what not for htmlspecialchars or htmlentities.

Answer (score 3):

[htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) works with ISO-8869-1 encoding by default prior to PHP5.4

Try supplying encoding parameter to a function call:

```
<?php echo htmlentities($page->title, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8');?>
```

No way to bypass supplying second parameter, though, but `ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401` is the default anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried and same as the suggestion from Pinetree, I only get Judge-Fürstová Mila instead of Judge-Fürstová Mila "Ut enim ad minim veniam"...

Comment: no sorry, I get this error message actually, `Use of undefined constant ENT_HTML401 - assumed 'ENT_HTML401' in <b>C:\wamp\www\xxx\form_page_update.php</b> on line ...`

Comment: @lauthiamkok ENT_HTML401 is only available on PHP 5.4+. Just remove the constant from the second parameter and everything should work fine and you'll get the string parsed just right.

Comment: sorry my mistake, German Rumm. I'm on 5.3.10... it now works with `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: @lauthiamkok, yeah, `htmlspecialchars()` is much better suited for your case.