# Only convert <, >, &, ' and " for XML?

Tags: php, pdo, preg-replace, special-characters, xml-entities

It seems I have another problem with special character and double quotes and so on after this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233071/special-characters-and-double-quotes-issue-in-php/) that has been solved earlier.

I used to use this function that convert symbol like '&' to numberic code for XML,

```
function convert_specialchars_to_xmlenties($string) 
{ 

    # in order to convert  <, >, &, ' and ", include them into the square brackes [<\'"&>\x80-\xff]
    $output = preg_replace('/([<\'"&>\x80-\xff])/e', "'&#' . ord('$1') . ';'", $string);

    # return the result
    return $output; 
}
```

So if my input is **Judge-Fürstová Mila & Judge-Fürstová Mila**

I will get `Judge-F&#252;rstov&#225; Mila &#38; Judge-F&#252;rstov&#225; Mila`

But I think since I am using `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"` to handle all my special characters, so if my input is something like

**Judge-Fürstová Mila & Judge-Fürstová Mila**

now will returns,

```
Judge-F&#195;&#188;rstov&#195;&#161; Mila &#38; Judge-F&#195;&#188;rstov&#195;&#161; Mila
```

Which is incorrect for XML I think.

So I think I should just convert **<, >, &, ' and "** only but not other special characters like **ü** or **á**

Any ideas I how I can do this? Or maybe I have thought/ understood the problem incorrectly and there are other better ways to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

I was wrong, as I just changed the function which only converts **<, >, &, ' and "**

```
$output = preg_replace('/([<\'"&>])/e', "'&#' . ord('$1') . ';'", $string);
```

XML still does not accept the converted code below,

```
Judge-Fürstová Mila &#38; Judge-Fürstová Mila
```

I cannot think of any other reason why it does that! Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)(). Don't let the name throw you off. It by default converts only the characters you've listed.

Comment: &amp; should still be used in xml

Comment: @lauthiamkok: Try `<x>&</x>` and see what your XML validator/parser spits out at you...

Comment: Hi Mark, I get `&lt;x&gt;&amp;&lt;/x&gt;` if I use `htmlspecialchars` and it still not accept by XML...

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is not safe for UTF-8.

Comment: @Kilink: In what way is `htmlspecialchars` not safe? According to the manual, "Calling htmlspecialchars() is sufficient if the encoding supports all characters in the input string (such us UTF-8...)."

Comment: sorry my mistake. `htmlspecialchars()` does it correctly. it was my xml document has other untidy codes. arg...!

Answer (score -1):

*Edited answer to cut out all the superfluous stuff and just keep the actual answer*

You want [`mb_ereg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace-callback.php), and the callback should handle multibyte characters. Something like:

```
$out = mb_ereg_replace_callback(
    "[<>&\"']",
    function($a) {
        $o = 0;
        $l = strlen($a[0]);
        for( $i=0; $i<$l; $i++) {
            $o = ($o << 8) | ord($a[$i]);
        }
        return "&#".$o.";";
    },
    $in);
```

Although in this case the callback would be fine with just a simple `ord`, you might want to reuse this code for other characters sometime.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I just tried it but it is still not getting any better, for instance `<x>&</x>` will get `&#60;&#120;&#62;&#38;&#60;&#47;&#120;&#62;` but the converted code still cannot be processed as XML...

Comment: I removed the useless stuff. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks Kolink, I get this error though `Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function mb_ereg_replace_callback() in...`

Comment: Ah, you don't have the mbstring module? Hmm... That kinda makes it hard to work with UTF-8...

Comment: I have php_mbstring turned on in warmpserver but I dunno why that function is undefined... maybe i'm on php 5.3.10...?